# regex pattern to match whole word or word followed by another

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm starting to learn regex in order to match words in python columns and replace them for other values.

```
df['col1']=df['col1'].str.replace(r'(?i)unlimi+\w*', 'Unlimited', regex=True)
```

This pattern serves to match different variations of the world Unlimited. But I have some values in the column that have not only one word, but two or more:
ex:

```
[Unlimited, Unlimited (on-net), Unlimited (on-off-net)]`
```

I was wondering if there is a way to match all of the words in the previous example with a single regex line.

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove any substring between parentheses after an `unlimited` word? Like `df['col1']=df['col1'].str.replace(r'(?i)unlimi\w*(?:\s*\([^()]*\))?', 'Unlimited', regex=True)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['col1']=df['col1'].str.replace(r'(?i)unlimi\w*(?:\s*\([^()]*\))?', 'Unlimited', regex=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0D0emq/1).

The `(?i)unlimi\w*(?:\s*\([^()]*\))?` regex matches

- `(?i)` - the regex to the right is case insensitive
- `unlimi` - a fixed string
- `\w*` - zero or more word chars
- `(?:\s*\([^()]*\))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
  - `\)` - a `)` char.